# XSLT in Java: CDATA section split

Tags: java, xml, xslt, cdata

I want to replace some items in a huge XML file, and I thought I'll do it with XSLT. I have absolutely no experience with it, so if you think there would be better ways to do this, please tell me.

Anyway, as a first step I just wanted to copy the whole XML over. This is my xsl file:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="no" cdata-section-elements="script"/>
  <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

The relevant Java code is:

```
Source xmlInput = new StreamSource(oldProjectStream);
Source xsl = new StreamSource("test.xsl");

Transformer transformer = TransformerFactory.newInstance().newTransformer(xsl);
StreamResult xmlOutput = new StreamResult("output/project.xml");
transformer.transform(xmlInput, xmlOutput);
```

Most of the output is fine, also the order of the elements is not changed (this could turn out quite important).

The XML contains some Lua code in CDATA sections. At some (seemingly random) points, however, the CDATA section is closed and reopened again. It seems to have to do with brackets in the code, but just rately - there are about 5 points in a 1.4 MB XML looking like this:

```
<script><![CDATA[
...
html_encoding["Otilde"  ] = string.char(213)
html_encoding["Ouml"    ]]]><![CDATA[ = string.char(214)
html_encoding["Oslash"  ] = string.char(216)
...
]]></script>
```

In the original file, the middle line looks just like the other ones. There are thousands of lines where I've put the dots. What's going on here?

The (proprietary) application that should handle the XML isn't able to load it.

Comment: StackTrace can be helpful.

Comment: Try removing `cdata-section-elements`. CDATA is a convenience facility that is completely unnecessary in XML. If your proprietary target application can handle XML *at all*, it will work. Then again, if your proprietary target application could handle XML at all, it should work already.

Comment: @Tomalak Why should it be unnecessary? < and > are not allowed as content in XML, but the code can contain them.

Comment: Yes, but `<` and `>` are easily encoded as `&lt;` and `&gt;` in XML, so this is not a restriction at all.

Comment: I'm not allowed to change the content of these sections, so I don't think this is an option.

Comment: I'm having this problem too. By debugging I see that the CDATA is closed and reopened at every line break, but sometimes it's done in the middle of text too. This can break stuff when that text needs to be processed by the code. I have no idea what's the cause of this behavior and haven't found anything online so far. @user2727133 did you find the culprit?

Comment: @nonzaprej No. The task turned out to be way too complicated to be handled by XSLT anyway, so I just worked in the Document created by SAXBuilder directly.

Comment: Well, in my case the faulty xml comes out of a SAXReader, so even before processing it with xsl. I'll have to find a workaround.

Answer (score 0):

It's useful to tell us which XSLT processor you are using.

The serializer has to close and reopen a CDATA section if it encounters `"]]>"` in the data, because that sequence cannot legally appear in a CDATA section. It shouldn't need to do so under any other circumstances, though the spec probably doesn't disallow it.